# How is bilateral asymmetry determined in embryonic development?

Tags: embryology, development

What are the mechanisms that ensure consistent left-right asymmetric placement of various internal organs (heart, liver, etc) or consistent left-right asymmetric development of paired organs (brain, etc.)? At what level, and how comprehensive is our current understanding about the underlying mechanisms?

(It seems to me a mirror image is just as good as the original one in terms of fitness and functionality. But why only one specific LR asymmetry prevails? Maybe this is a misguided way to think about the problem but that motivated to ask anyway.)

Comment: There are two morphogens called [lefty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefty_%28protein%29) and its antagonist [nodal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NODAL). Their signalling and interaction gives rise to the right-left asymmetry. However, to answer your question fully, one would have to look up on how exactly are lefty and nodal regulated.